# Fragment not showing properly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am learning Kotlin, have done apps in Java before. I now have an activity with an `Toolbar`, `NavigationView` and a `FragmentView`. As I understand this: [Fragment Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create), it is enough to state the Fragment in the xml file.

I have this `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_app_bar_layout"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:name="com.example.android.camerax.tflite.TestFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the `fragment_test.xml`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.camerax.tflite.TestFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the `Activity`:

```
class CameraActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private lateinit var fragment: CameraActivityFragment
    private lateinit var navigationDrawer: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera)

        navigationDrawer = findViewById(R.id.navigation_container)
        // Handle user consent update
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            navigationDrawer,
            toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        navigationDrawer.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        val navigationView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_navigation)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.show_recordings) {
//             Start ListView
        }
        navigationDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

and here is the `TestFragment.kt`:

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            TestFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I have tried to read the link above and also follow this: [AndroidTrivia](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/tree/master/AndroidTriviaFragment). No success and I really think this is quite basic and should work. When I run the debugger I can see that `onCreateView` is called in the Fragment, as it should be.

This is how it looks. Sometimes, the text blips on the screen. So seems like something is overwriting the fragment?

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5lHZ.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KF1g.png)

**Edit**
After updating the `FragmentContainerView` with elevation `9dp`, the text is shown. But now the Toolbar is hidden, although there is a marginTop for the `FragmentContainerView`. [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpMjZ.png)

Comment: Can you add an image of what is visible on the screen right now? Is only the fragment missing or is the toolbar missing too?

Comment: Yes, the text bliped now, so it seems to be overwritten!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I would like to suggest here.

- First if possible get back to `ConstraintLayout` as in your last answer. It is not necessary for sure, but would recommend.
- Second the blipping might be cause by the difference in `elevation` since the `elevation` of `NavigationView` is different.

So I suggest you add the following to your `FragmentContainerView`

```xml
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:elevation="9dp"
        android:name="com.example.android.camerax.tflite.TestFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test" />
```

`9dp` since most Android Views like `BottomNav` etc are upto `8dp`

Also would recommend to modify your `fragment_test` as follows and add the following

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.camerax.tflite.TestFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, adding the elevation made the text visible! Had completely forgotten that property. I do not understand what you mean with go back to ConstraintLayout? Also, now the `Toolbar` is hidden, although the `FragmentContainer` has the attribute `marginTop` set.

Comment: @El_Loco You were earlier using both `ConstraintLayout` and `DrawerLayout` right. You seem to have removed it now. It would be much easier to manage constraints that way as you could assign your `FragmentContainer` below `Toolbar` instead of depdending upon margins.

Could you add picture of how it is looking now? The `Toolbar` should not be hidden as far as I know.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, thought I had reverted. :) There should be an image in the question after Edit.

Comment: Inserting the constraint layout as you suggested in the previous question seems to do the trick!. Many thanks!

Comment: Quite subtle with the elevation though. :)

Comment: No worries. I would suggest you keep at it with `ConstraintLayout` though. It might seem inconvenient but it is a big help.